# How can I create a web app where I can read text from a sheet based on dropdown selections?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown

I am trying to create a role description generator which reads pre-written text from a Google Sheet and assembles it in blocks in a web app through selections (team, role, seniority level, etc.) in dropdown menus.

This is an example of what the data in the sheet looks like:

| Team name | Team description |
| --- | --- |
| A-team | Description |
| B-team | Description |
| ... | ... |

So far, for the team selection, I have created the dropdown menu which reads the data from the sheet, and pulls the names of each team into a dropdown list. But my problem is loading the corresponding team description text into the HTML page. I just can't seem to get it to work.

When pressing the generate button, what should happen is that the description for A-team is loaded, but instead I get `[object MouseEvent]`.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance! :)

[image]

Here's my code:

**Code.gs**

```
var url = "*spreadsheet URL*";

function doGet(e) {
  
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
  .evaluate()
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  
}

//get the data for the dropdown list
function valuesForList(list) {
  
  //define the data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
  var teamsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var lastRow = teamsSheet.getLastRow();
  var teamsRange = teamsSheet.getRange(1, 3, lastRow, 1);
  
  //create a named range
  ss.setNamedRange('teamsList', teamsRange);
  
  //get the values from the range
  var listValues = ss.getRangeByName(list).getValues();
  
  return listValues;
   
}

//the function to show the data on the index.html
function PostInfo (userInfo){
  
  //load the data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Teams"); 
  var data = ws.getRange(2,1,ws2.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
  
  var teamList = data.map(function(r){ return r[0]});
  var teamDesc = data.map(function(r){ return r[1]});
  
  var position = teamList.indexOf(userInfo.teams);
  if(position > -1){
    
    return teamDesc[position]; 
    
  } else {
  
  return "Unavailable";
  }
  
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css"> 
    
    <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('css').getContent(); ?>
  
    <script>
   
    function onListSuccess(list) {
    
      var listLength = list.length;
      
      for (i=0; i<listLength;i++) {
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("teams");
        
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        
        dropdown.options.add(opt);
        
        opt.text = list[i][0];
        opt.value = list[i][0];
              
      }
       
    }    
       
    function onListSelect(teamDesc){
    
    var text = teamDesc.toString().split(",");
    
    document.getElementById('est').innerHTML = text;  
  }
  
    
  </script>
 
  </head>
  
  
  <body>
    <div id="main">
    <h1>Role Description Generator</h1>
    <p>
      <label for="teams">Team:</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <select name="teams" id="teams" tabindex="2"></select>
    </p>
        <button id="btn">Generate</button>
    <div>   
       <label for="est">Team description:</label>
        <p id="est" name="est"></p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  
  
  <script>
 
  function populateList(){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onListSuccess).valuesForList('teamsList');
  }
   
   
  document.getElementById("teams").addEventListener("change", doStuff);
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", onListSelect);
    
  function doStuff(){
  
  var userInfo = {};
  
  userInfo.teams = document.getElementById("teams").value;
  
  google.script.run.PostInfo(userInfo);
  
  }
  
  window.addEventListener('load', populateList);
  
  </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modification points:

- In your script, when the dropdown list is changed, `doStuff()` is run. But in this case, `google.script.run.PostInfo(userInfo)` runs only the function of `PostInfo` at Google Apps Script. By this, the returned value is not used.
- And, when the button is clicked, `onListSelect` is run. But in this case, `teamDesc` of `onListSelect(teamDesc)` is the event object. By this, such value of `[object MouseEvent]` is shown. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.
- By the way, when I saw your Google Apps Script, I noticed that `PostInfo` has a modification point. When `var data = ws.getRange(2,1,ws2.getLastRow(),2).getValues();` is run, I think that an error occurs. Because `ws2` is not declared. In your case, is that `ws`? I thought that this might be due to your miscopy.

When you want to show the value from `PostInfo` when the button is clicked, how about the following modification?

### Modified script:

#### HTML&Javascript side:

From:

```
document.getElementById("teams").addEventListener("change", doStuff);
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", onListSelect);
  
function doStuff(){

var userInfo = {};

userInfo.teams = document.getElementById("teams").value;

google.script.run.PostInfo(userInfo);

}
```

To:

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);

function doStuff(){
  var userInfo = {};
  userInfo.teams = document.getElementById("teams").value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onListSelect).PostInfo(userInfo);
}
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

From:

```
var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Teams"); 
var data = ws.getRange(2,1,ws2.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
```

To:

```
var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Teams"); 
var data = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
```

### Note:

- In this modidication, it supposes that the Google Apps Script works fine and returns the correct values. Please be careful this.

### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)